# Multi-key container with OR search capabilities

Tags: c++, qt, containers

I'm looking for a container which can hold multiple keys where if I enter a reserved value (such as 0) for one of the key values, it is considered as an "OR" search.

```
map< pair<int, int>, int > myContainer;

myContainer.insert(make_pair(1, 1), 650);
myContainer.insert(make_pair(2, 4), 827);
myContainer.insert(make_pair(3, 1), 5);
myContainer.insert(make_pair(3, 2), 943254);

pair<int, int> key1 = make_pair(1, 1);
pair<int, int> key2 = make_pair(3, 0);
pair<int, int> key3 = make_pair(0, 1);
pair<int, int> key4 = make_pair(0, 0);

auto it = myContainer.find(key1);
cout << it->second << endl;      // it->second is an array or vector or values

it = myContainer.find(key2);
cout << it->second << endl;      // I know this isn't how to output all values in a vector

it = myContainer.find(key3);
cout << it->second << endl;      // But this demonstrates the sort of thing I'm after

it = myContainer.find(key4);
cout << it->second << endl;
```

Desired output:

```
650
5, 943254
650, 5
650, 827, 5, 943254
```

I'm working with a variety of data which interlinks with multiple algorithms. However the information each algorithm possesses isn't enough to fully define all the keys correctly to collect each individual packet of information. At a later stage all of the information will be passed onto a more central database (probably using SQLite or something, don't know at this stage).

I'm still relatively new to much of C++, and currently don't know anything about databases. I do on the other hand have some time on my hands to learn things. Sorry if this is a vague question, but with the possibility of having to learn at least 1 new language on the cards I figured I may as well ask for some directions! Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Currently using: Qt with C++ on Windows 7 or Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I seems that you need to implement your own class. I don't think that STL has something out of the box for your needs.

Comment: I've made a couple of classes before, but never anything as complex as what this container would need to do. It has similarities to what you can do in an SQL database, but I don't know enough about SQL, let alone how to integrate them to work in a fast manner. Any pointers in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if it completely fits your need, but maybe you should look at [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).

Comment: This seems more like a *wildcard* than an *OR* operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variation on Brandon's answer:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

struct element{int k1,k2,data;};

typedef multi_index_container<
  element,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_unique<
      composite_key<
        element,
        member<element,int,&element::k1>,
        member<element,int,&element::k2>
      >
    >,
    ordered_non_unique<member<element,int,&element::k2>>
  >
> multi_t;

typedef boost::any_range<
  element,
  boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag,
  const element&,
  std::ptrdiff_t
> range_t;

inline range_t range(const multi_t& m,const std::pair<int,int>& k)
{
  if(k.second==0){
    if(k.first==0){
      return range_t(m.begin(),m.end());
    }
    else{
      auto p=m.equal_range(k.first);
      return range_t(p.first,p.second);
    }
  }
  else if(k.first==0){
    auto p=m.get<1>().equal_range(k.second);
    return range_t(p.first,p.second);
  }
  else{
    auto p=m.equal_range(boost::make_tuple(k.first,k.second));
    return range_t(p.first,p.second);
  }
}

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const range_t& r)
{
  for(const auto& e:r){
    os<<e.data<<",";
  }
  return os;
}

int main()
{
  multi_t m={{1,1,650},{2,4,827},{3,1,5},{3,2,943254}};
  std::cout<<range(m,{1,1})<<"\n";
  std::cout<<range(m,{3,0})<<"\n";
  std::cout<<range(m,{0,1})<<"\n";
  std::cout<<range(m,{0,0})<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Apologies for taking a while to come back to you, I had to install boost for Qt to test this out. It has just the right characteristics I was looking for. Looks like I'll be spending my learning time looking into the basics of boost, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that works (well... it covers your inputs) which uses boost::multi-index:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;

template <typename T, typename KeyElementType = int>
class or_container
{
    typedef KeyElementType key_element_type;

    struct default_index{};
    struct keyx_index{};
    struct keyy_index{};

    struct datum
    {
        datum(const std::pair<key_element_type, key_element_type>& key, T value)
            : key_x(key.first)
            , key_y(key.second)
            , value(value)
        {
            assert(0 != key_x);
            assert(0 != key_y);
        }

        datum(key_element_type key_x, key_element_type key_y, T value)
            : key_x(key_x)
            , key_y(key_y)
            , value(value)
        {
            assert(0 != key_x);
            assert(0 != key_y);
        }

        std::pair<key_element_type, key_element_type> get_key() const
        {
            return std::make_pair(key_x, key_y);
        }

        operator const T& () const
        {
            return value;
        }

        operator T& ()
        {
            return value;
        }

        key_element_type key_x;
        key_element_type key_y;
        T value;
    };

    typedef multi_index_container
        <
            datum
          , indexed_by
            <
                ordered_non_unique<tag<default_index>, const_mem_fun<datum, std::pair<key_element_type, key_element_type>, &datum::get_key> >
              , ordered_non_unique<tag<keyx_index>, member<datum, key_element_type, &datum::key_x> >
              , ordered_non_unique<tag<keyy_index>, member<datum, key_element_type, &datum::key_y> >
            >
        > container;

    container m_cont;

public:

    typedef std::pair<key_element_type, key_element_type> key_type;

    or_container()
    {}

    //! precondition: key indices do not contain 0 values.
    //! @return whether the value was inserted for the specified key.
    bool insert(key_type key, const T& value)
    {
        assert(key.first != 0 && key.second != 0);            
        if (!key.first || !key.second)
            return false;

        return m_cont.insert(datum(key, value)).second;
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return m_cont.size(); }

    std::set< std::reference_wrapper<const T> > find(key_type key) const
    {
        std::set< std::reference_wrapper<const T> > values;
        if (key.first != 0 && key.second != 0)
        {
            const auto& index = m_cont.get<default_index>();
            std::transform(index.lower_bound(key), index.upper_bound(key), std::inserter(values, values.end()), [](const datum& d){ return std::reference_wrapper<const T>(d); });
        }
        else if (key.first == 0 && key.second == 0)
        {
            std::transform(m_cont.begin(), m_cont.end(), std::inserter(values, values.end()), [](const datum& d){ return std::reference_wrapper<const T>(d); });
        }
        else
        {
            if (key.first == 0)
            {
                const auto& index = m_cont.get<keyy_index>();
                std::transform(index.lower_bound(key.second), index.upper_bound(key.second), std::inserter(values, values.end()), [](const datum& d){ return std::reference_wrapper<const T>(d); });
            }
            if (key.second == 0)
            {
                const auto& index = m_cont.get<keyx_index>();
                std::transform(index.lower_bound(key.first), index.upper_bound(key.first), std::inserter(values, values.end()), [](const datum& d){ return std::reference_wrapper<const T>(d); });
            }
        }

        return values;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Cmp, typename Alloc>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::set<T, Cmp, Alloc>& s)
{
    os << "{ ";
    int i = 0;
    for (T value : s)
    {
        if (i++)
            os << ", ";
        os << value;
    };
    os << " }";
    return os;
}

int main()
{ 
    using namespace std;
    or_container<int> myContainer;

    myContainer.insert(make_pair(1, 1), 650);
    myContainer.insert(make_pair(2, 4), 827);
    myContainer.insert(make_pair(3, 1), 5);
    myContainer.insert(make_pair(3, 2), 943254);

    pair<int, int> key1 = make_pair(1, 1);
    pair<int, int> key2 = make_pair(3, 0);
    pair<int, int> key3 = make_pair(0, 1);
    pair<int, int> key4 = make_pair(0, 0);

    auto s = myContainer.find(key1);
    cout << s << endl;      // it->second is an array or vector or values

    s = myContainer.find(key2);
    cout << s << endl;      // I know this isn't how to output all values in a vector

    s = myContainer.find(key3);
    cout << s << endl;      // But this demonstrates the sort of thing I'm after

    s = myContainer.find(key4);
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

{ 650 }

{ 5, 943254 }

{ 5, 650 }

{ 5, 650, 827, 943254 }

Strictly speaking, boost::multi_index isn't necessary. It's just likely more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that just uses the stl (and C++03 I think) with some of the optimizations Joaquín has put forth:

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename KeyElementType = int>
class or_container
{
    typedef KeyElementType key_element_type;

    struct datum
    {
        datum(const std::pair<key_element_type, key_element_type>& key, T value)
            : key(key)
            , value(value)
        {
            assert(0 != key.first);
            assert(0 != key.second);
        }

        operator const T& () const
        {
            return value;
        }

        bool operator <(const datum& rhs) const
        {
            return key < rhs.key;
        }

        bool operator <(const key_element_type& rhs) const
        {
            return key.first < rhs;
        }

        friend bool operator <(const key_element_type& lhs, const datum& rhs)
        {
            return lhs < rhs.key.first;
        }

        bool operator <(const std::pair<key_element_type, key_element_type>& rhs) const
        {
            return key < rhs;
        }

        friend bool operator <(const std::pair<key_element_type, key_element_type>& lhs, const datum& rhs)
        {
            return lhs < rhs.key;
        }

        std::pair<key_element_type, key_element_type> key;
        T value;
    };

    typedef std::multiset<datum> data_set;
    typedef typename data_set::iterator datum_iterator;
    data_set m_cont;

    typedef std::multimap<key_element_type, datum_iterator> y_index;
    y_index m_yindex;

public:

    typedef std::pair<key_element_type, key_element_type> key_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;

    or_container()
    {}

    //! precondition: key indices do not contain 0 values.
    //! @return whether the value was inserted for the specified key.
    bool insert(key_type key, const T& value)
    {
        assert(key.first != 0 && key.second != 0);
        if (!key.first || !key.second)
            return false;

        datum_iterator it = m_cont.insert(datum(key, value));
        m_yindex.insert(std::make_pair(key.second, it)); 
        return true;
    }

    std::size_t size() const { return m_cont.size(); }

    std::multiset<T> find(const key_type& key) const
    {
        struct deref_map_iter_value
        {
            const_reference operator()(const typename y_index::value_type& item) { return *item.second; }
        };

        std::multiset<T> values;
        if (key.second == 0)
            if (key.first == 0)
                std::copy(m_cont.begin(), m_cont.end(), std::inserter(values, values.end()));
            else
                std::copy(std::lower_bound(m_cont.begin(), m_cont.end(), key.first), std::upper_bound(m_cont.begin(), m_cont.end(), key.first), std::inserter(values, values.end()));
        else if (key.first == 0)
            std::transform(m_yindex.lower_bound(key.second), m_yindex.upper_bound(key.second), std::inserter(values, values.end()), deref_map_iter_value());
        else
            std::copy(std::lower_bound(m_cont.begin(), m_cont.end(), key), std::upper_bound(m_cont.begin(), m_cont.end(), key), std::inserter(values, values.end()));

        return values;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Cmp, typename Alloc>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::multiset<T, Cmp, Alloc>& s)
{
    os << "{ ";
    int i = 0;
    for (T value : s)
    {
        if (i++)
            os << ", ";
        os << value;
    };
    os << " }";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    or_container<int> myContainer;

    myContainer.insert(make_pair(1, 1), 650);
    myContainer.insert(make_pair(2, 4), 827);
    myContainer.insert(make_pair(3, 1), 5);
    myContainer.insert(make_pair(3, 2), 943254);

    pair<int, int> key1 = make_pair(1, 1);
    pair<int, int> key2 = make_pair(3, 0);
    pair<int, int> key3 = make_pair(0, 1);
    pair<int, int> key4 = make_pair(0, 0);

    std::multiset<int> s = myContainer.find(key1);
    cout << s << endl;      // it->second is an array or vector or values

    s = myContainer.find(key2);
    cout << s << endl;      // I know this isn't how to output all values in a vector

    s = myContainer.find(key3);
    cout << s << endl;      // But this demonstrates the sort of thing I'm after

    s = myContainer.find(key4);
    cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```